# Instruments and memory leak

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am doing like this in the init of my Object :

```
-(id)initWithBookPath:(NSString*)path {
if (self = [super init]){

self.path = [self.fileSystemPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
...

}
return self;
}
```

the path is declared as : `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *path;`

when i launch instruments, it show me a leak at this line, is this a real memory leak ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Have you allocated the object path?

Comment: path is a property, the problem is i have not do self.path =nil in the dealoc mmethod

Comment: deallocate your self.path in Dealloc and didUnload method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers, instruments show me a leak because i have not do : `self.path =nil;` in the `dealoc` method. thanks for your answers.